# track 65 miles -- is "track" an adjective here?

Tags: adjectives

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/metrolink-train-strikes-truck-southern-california-143339051.html):

> The train carrying 51 passengers was heading from Ventura County to Los Angeles. The stretch of **track 65 miles** from Los Angeles where the collision occurred was straight, and that allowed the conductor to see the truck on the tracks and begin braking, fire officials said. The speed limit in the area for trains was 79 mph.

Is the word *track* used as an adjective to describe what kind of 65 miles the stretch was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misparsed this. The long subject of this sentence is a noun phrase headed formally by the noun *stretch*. That word means an extent or piece of something which 'stretches' from one point to another. What that 'something' is—what the *stretch* is a stretch **of** is

- **stretch of track** ... *that is, what we are dealing with is a small part of the entire line of track*.

The next pieces locates that stretch of track by reference to the city: it is

- **65 miles from Los Angeles**

The particular stretch of track is identified by means of a relative clause:

- **where the collision occurred**

The main clause describes the stretch of track:

> The stretch of track ... was straight.